# In scala IDE in eclispse Juno I have build issues to run a scala program

Tags: scala

I am getting the following error when i try to execute the scala program for connecting hbase and spark.
Error: Could not find or load main class examples.HBaseRead

Answer (score 0):

Scala class didn't compile. You can check the Output folder like bin or target. In my case re installing eclipse scala plugin resolved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You need to Scala perspective 
1.Right click-Properties->Select Scala interpreter->you can select installed location.

Now its working...

Or

Download Eclipse
go to market place and type scalaIDE 
install it...

then project --properties-->convert Scala perspective..
Now its working...TRY